# Override property in "style=" attribute?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adjust the position of the background image of a button in CKEditor.

CKEditor hard-codes button images with `background-position: 0px 0pt`. I don't want to change this, as it seems to be in the editor's core.

I can, however, set a custom class for the button and style that in the style sheet. But because the background-position statement is made in the style attribute, I can't overwrite it from a class, not even using `!important`.

**Is there any way to override a CSS property in the `style=` attribute in a CSS class?**

I don't think there is. Anybody know any workarounds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to override the properties specified in a `style` attribute is to use [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules).

Comment: Didn't know !important was THAT "important"!  I learned something today!

Comment: It's not so intuitive... marking a property as "not important" in your CSS styles makes it so important that it overrides the element-level styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the style with some Javascript, or (even better yet) use some JQuery to do it for you.