# jquery - override Google Ad 728px width format

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, google-ads-api, banner-ads

I'm supposed to make a PC site readable on mobile devices. I'm using Jquery Mobile CSS, which works quite ok.

The problem: the current site uses some Google 728x90px banners, which break my mobile layout.

**Question**
Is there any way to Jquery-set their width to 100%?

I can add borders using this Jquery (although the banner loads first, so this already breaks my layout), but I can't set the width like this.

```
$('.widget-content ins, .widget-content img').css({ 'border':'5px solid red', 'width':'22px !important'});
```

Can this be done any better? Would I want to do this?

What would be a workaround if a site uses Jquery-Mobile to display across all devices (PC&mobile) and the ads are just configured for desktop?

Thanks for some inputs and hopefully an easy Jquery "patch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this to edit the `ins` of the google ad:

```
   $($('ins').first()).css({
        ...
   })
```

Comment: Can't edit the width like this, because width is set on the element via style=""; Any idea how to override this?

Comment: Got it. Plain CSS using important works. Here is the question on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933248/override-property-in-style-attribute

Comment: Another way of doing it is with .style.width="100%"