# Is there a simple way to overwrite a stylesheet with inline style?

Tags: html, html-table

Given a table that I want to integrate into a cCMS site, the overall stylesheet overwrites the inline style of the table... how can I prevent the stylesheet from doing it?

The table I have looks something like this and gets overwritten by the stylesheet...

```
<table id="idferthis" BORDER=1 RULES=NONE FRAME=BOX width="644" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <th id="toptopper" bgcolor="#6a8044" align="right" scope="row">HIPHOO</th>
    <td bgcolor="#afd46c" align="center">SOMETHIN</td>
    <td bgcolor="#afd46c" align="center">SOMETHINELSE</td>
  </tr>
....
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you using inline styles instead of including a stylesheet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override property in "style=" attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933248/override-property-in-style-attribute)

Comment: @Zirak ...because im too lazy to translate the tables into proper css...and there a a lot of this individual tables...;-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this after the element you want to be overriden

!important;

so an example would be

```
<td style="color:#000; !important;">Black Text</td>
```

This would override a style sheet with black text.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `style` attribute for the table,

this means `style="border-width:1; width:644px; ..."`

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS rules to style your table, inline CSS takes precedence over included.

For example, instead of using the bgcolor attribute, use the background-color CSS property, e.g.:

```
<td style="background-color: #afd46c;" align="center">SOMETHINELSE</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css file write a style for the rendered control and apply `!important` to the style.

Eg.

`table td {background-color: red !important;}`