# Jevents (joomla) month calendar cell size

Tags: css, joomla

Right now, the month calendar cell is of height 80px, which I reckon is too much. I want to change the rows with days. I tried doing inspect element and found the name table class to be `cal_table` and added `table.cal_table tr{height:40px}` to the `template.css` file.

[image: JEvents Month Calendar Cell Size]

As seen above, it increased the height of the first row where the days of the week are displayed, to 40px and retained the heights of the others. What I want, on the contrary, is to retain the height of the first row and reduce those of the rest to 40px. My analysis of the situation is the following:

As in the above I see that in the first `<tr>` element, there is no `style` attribute set. So the height setting added in the template works. Whereas in the subsequent `<tr>` elements there is a `style` attribute in which is the 80px height setting, which I reckon is the reason the setting I added in the template is overridden. I want to remove `style="height:80px"`, but I found it tough searching the `com_jevents` folder in which it is set and felt as if it were a needle-in-a-haystack problem!

I somehow want to have the setting added in `template.css` override the setting in the `style` attribute as in the picture, or better, just get rid of the style="height:80px". Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I right-clicked a row in the month calendar cell and found the class of the element. Then set the property in `template.css` and to override all inline styles, did as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933248/override-property-in-style-attribute)! Thanks to StackOverflow once again!!