# Can I adjust the font-size relatively, when the font-size is already defined in the HTML-code?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I've been looking for the right answer for this on the internet, but couldn't find anything that works.

This is my HTML-code:

```
<div id="wrapper3">

    <div id="content">
            <p><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:14px">
this is text</span></span>&nbsp;</p><p><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif; font-size:14px">this is text</span></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

The code from the first <p> until the last </p> is generated by a wysiwyg-programm, so I can't change that (it's downloaded from my phpMyAdmin-database).
However, I want to enlarge the font-size 3 times of this text via CSS (or via another way, if anyone of you knows a better way).
So everything that's 14px right now, I want that to be 42px. However, I am not able to change this in the HTML code. For some reason, this doesn't work:

```
#content {font-size:3em;} // or:
#content p {font-size:3em;} // or:
#content p span {font-size:3em;}
```

It doesn't work with 300% instead of 3em, either.
Does anyone know how I should do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show how the font size is initially set, please.

Comment: You can use !important as this answer suggests.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/1933269/2816674

Comment: +1 to @Sinomai. Since you're using inline styles that's the option you're going to have to go with.

Comment: You can do font-size: 42px !important; or you can use js to remove the inline styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ym8sN/) shows the code you'll need to add to your CSS:

```
      #content span {
        font-size: 42px!important;
     }
```

Comment: I hate to use !important, but sometimes it is the way.

Comment: I agree with you @DrCord, but I don't see another option if the template is not modifiable...